# Should a typecast to a unsigned long reference be used while calling a function or another unsigned long variable should be created?

Tags: c++, reference

I was working on a code base where I have a function definition like this:

```
int TaskM::GetDefaultValues(unsigned long ccId, unsigned long at, unsigned long& sId, string& dName, void * db = NULL);
```

The task of above function is to assign `sId` some value based on the logic inside the function.

I need to call this function in my code, which I am currently doing like

```
StatusInfo SetRespMessage(StatResp i_res)
{
    TaskM cobj;
    cobj.GetDefaultValues((unsigned long)i_res.ccid, (unsigned long)i_res.at, (unsigned long&)i_res.sId, i_res.status)
}
```

See the argument `(unsigned long&)i_res.sId`, I was wondering if this is good or should I create another variable here like

```
unsigned long newVar;
cobj.GetDefaultValues((unsigned long)i_res.ccid, (unsigned long)i_res.at, newVar, i_res.status)
i_res.sId = newVar;
```

Apart from the fact that I am creating another variable, is there any performance difference or anything else that I should consider while coding this way?

Comment: Sorry about that. The name `MyFunctionName` looked too generic.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ no problem, thanks for understanding.

Comment: There's nowhere near enough context to be able to review this code.  You should show sufficient _real_ code, with enough explanation to explain what function it provides to its caller, and the title needs improving to summarise _what the code is for_ rather than your concerns about it.

Comment: First of all enough context is available. And that's real code apart from the function name which I changed here(added real function name). Regarding the title I agree on that, hence edited! I seriously don't understand what context you need here, please enlighten us

Comment: I disagree.  Firstly, the title doesn't say what the code is for.  Secondly, we're completely missing any definition of `TaskM`, `string`, `StatusInfo`, `StatResp` and `cobj`, and there's no indication of what any of those represent.  It's completely unreviewable, whatever you insist on claiming.

Comment: BTW, Code Review is not the place for "a simple yes/no" question.  As the [Help/on-topic] says, it's the place for getting _**open-ended feedback**_ on __*any or all facets of the code*__.

Comment: When I said yes/no, of course I did not mean it in literal sense. Anyone who read my question would understand what I meant by yes/no. But I would again mention it for you since you did not read the question "The question specifically talks about the convention, style and the correct practice to call a function with a different parameter type than arguments"

Comment: Before you argue with the Moderators or more experienced users who help moderate this site I suggest you do more reading, please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This question was closed by 3 members of the community.

Comment: The question was closed because of herd mentality. Moderators take it in their ego, how can a fresher on this site dare question a moderator. An attack of question to one moderator is an attack to all is what their thinking is. Although you advertise Be nice Be respectful but it is the moderator who themselves seems to forget what they preach.

Comment: Dude, the moderators are trying as much as they can to help you get a good quality review. And you don't give a duck to help reviewers to actually understand what they're about to review. You're asking a question of the form "Is red wine better than white?" We can flood you with opinionated answers, but the only true answer is "it depends". But CR is not here to answer such questions. You've come to the wrong place so please be so kind and think twice before you start abusing those trying to help you.

Comment: Dude using the word "duck" And telling me that I abused others. You show me one comment from above where I abused anyone. I had my opinion and I stated the same, it was the moderators who started downvoting because I did not agree with one of them. Moreover do you really wanna find out what questions are best suited on this site, right now if I start auditing I ll show you 100 questions that were not closed/downvoted when it should have been. My question was far better than them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First reaction was C-Style casts are bad anyway.

I don't think your question says what type `i_res.sId` is, I'm going to assume its a 32bit uint.

If you are compiling for a 32bit machine this probably means the an unsigned in and unsigned long are the same size.  If its 64 bit then ulong *could* be 64bits and a uint *could* be 32bits.

The chances are you will get away with just doing the `(unsigned long&)` cast, but if it does go wrong then you are probably going to overflow into the next fireld in the `i_res` structure and you might not notice this until its too late.  It will be an expensive bug to find and fix.

To answer your question introduce a new variable to make it easier to find when it no longer works.

The answer I wan't to say is there shouldn;t be any casting and the structures should hold the right types, but thats probably not practical.

Comment: Yes all numeric variable in i_res are of `long type`